# Do routing specs support redirect routes? [RSpec]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

After digging fairly deeply on this issue, I've come to an impasse between my understanding of the documentation and my results.

According to https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/v/2-8/docs/routing-specs/route-to-matcher, we should be able to write the following:

```
#rspec-rails (2.8.1)
#rspec (>= 1.3.1)
#rspec-core (~> 2.8.0)

# routing spec
require "spec_helper"

describe BusinessUsersController do
  describe "routing" do
    it "routes to some external url" do
      get("/business_users/7/external_url").should route_to("http://www.google.com")
    end
  end
end

# routes.rb
BizeebeeBilling::Application.routes.draw do

  resources :business_users do
    member do
      get "external_url" => redirect("http://www.google.com")
    end
  end
end
```

Running this spec produces the following results:
    Failures:

```
  1) BusinessUsersController routing routes to some external url
     Failure/Error: assert_routing "/business_users/7/external_url", "http://www.google.com"
     ActionController::RoutingError:
       No route matches "/business_users/7/external_url"
     # ./spec/routing/business_users_routing_spec.rb:19:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

I have not been able to find anyone reporting this specific issue anywhere.

Added detail: the route is resolved perfectly well when testing manually.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Routing specs/tests specialize in testing whether a route maps to a specific controller and action (and maybe some parameters too).

I dug into the internals of Rails and Journey a bit. RSpec and Rails (basically, some details left out) use `Rails.application.routes.recognize_path` to answer the question "is this routable?"

For example:

```
$ rails console
> Rails.application.routes.recognize_path("/business_users/1", method: "GET")
 => {:action=>"show", :controller=>"business_users", :id=>"1"}
```

However, there's no controller on the other end of `/business_users/1/external_url`. In fact, to perform the redirect, Rails has created an instance of [`ActionDispatch::Routing::Redirect`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v3.2.5/actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/routing/redirection.rb), which is a small Rack application. No Rails controller is ever touched. You're basically mounting another Rack application to perform the redirection.

To test the redirect, I recommend using a request spec instead (a file in `spec/requests`). Something like:

```
require "spec_helper"

describe "external redirection" do
  it "redirects to google.com" do
    get "/business_users/1/external_url"
    response.should redirect_to("http://www.google.com")
  end
end
```

This tests the route implicitly, and allows you to test against the redirection.

Comment: This is good to understand, but I ran into a problem when trying this. In my Rspec `before` block I load up `seeds.rb` since there is some baseline data needed even in testing.  But since the redirect uses a tiny Rack app, loading `seeds.rb` fails with "could not find table" for any of my models, presumably because the non-Rails Rack applet doesn't use ActiveRecord.  So I'm left with no good way to have regressions for my redirect-based routes, which do work in the app but I can't get a test to pass for them.  :-(

Comment: `expect(response).to redirect_to("http://www.google.com")`
if you don't like 'should' syntax.

Answer (score 25):

Andy Lindeman has the correct answer. However, you don't have to put the spec in spec/requests, you can keep it in spec/routing and be explicit with the metadata "type": `describe 'my route', type: :request do`

Comment: I tried this, but still not finding the response object in the context of the spec

Comment: After fiddling around with it a bit, it looks like rspec is not letting me override the type of specs in the spec/routing path. If I move it outsite and put it under spec/request or spec/api, it ust works. I'll open an issue in rspec-rails for this.

Answer (score 10):

I was running into a similar case where I was trying to test a series of routes, some which should redirect and some which shouldn't. I wanted to keep them in a single routing spec, since that was the most logical way to group them.

I tried using `describe: 'my route', type: request`, but found that not to work. However, you can include `RSpec::Rails::RequestExampleGroup` in your spec context to gain access to the request spec methods. Something like:

```
describe "My Routes" do
  context "Don't Redirect" do
    it "gets URL that doesn't redirect" do
      get("business_users/internal_url").should route_to(controller: "business_users", action: "internal_url_action")
    end
  end

  context "Redirection" do
    include RSpec::Rails::RequestExampleGroup
    it "redirects to google.com" do
      get "/business_users/1/external_url"
      response.should redirect_to("http://www.google.com")
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score -1):

The simplest way to test external redirects is to use an integration test:

```
  test "GET /my_page redirects Google" do
    get "/my_page"
    assert_redirected_to "https://google.com"
  end
```

You test needs to be under your `test/integration` directory or the equivalent directory where the integration tests should go.

Comment: in rspec this would be a request spec

Answer (score -3):

I think you want the [redirect_to matcher](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/v/2-8/docs/matchers/redirect-to-matcher).

Comment: The redirect_to matcher is not available in routing specs. Furthermore, the error is not in the matcher, but in that the route, which is clearly defined in routes.rb is not being picked up when running the tests. As an additional point, the route itself works perfectly well when testing manually.

Comment: If it's not a controller spec, then why does it begin with `describe BusinessUsersController`?

Comment: You're right about that. However, those were generated. I suppose that's a separate issue altogether :(