# RSpec routing spec fails for custom match

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

A RSpec test fails with a custom URL matcher.

routes.rb:

```
get 'a/:code' => redirect(Rails.application.config.url_homepage)
```

spec/routing/routes_routing_spec.rb

```
describe 'routing' do
  describe "activation Urls" do

    it "redirects /a/:code to the public homepage" do
      get('/a/12341234').should route_to(Rails.application.config.url_homepage)
    end

  end
end
```

RSpec output:

```
  1) routing activation URLS redirects /a/:code to the public homepage
     Failure/Error: get('/a/12341234').should route_to(Rails.application.config.url_homepage)
       No route matches "/a/12341234"
     # ./spec/routing/routes_routing_spec.rb:7:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

The routing works - once I open such URL in the browser I will be redirected properly.

Do I miss a crucial detail?

Comment: Hey do you really want to test routes? I've never seen an app test routes before. I've found that it's more useful to do integration tests or controller tests.

Comment: Yes I do. Especially in this case, validation of the redirect is required.

Comment: Do you want to have a leading slash or remove the leading slash?  Experimenting with that might solve the problem.

Comment: @DavidGrayson yes I tried all combinations here without luck. And as said - it works, just RSpec fails.

Comment: Could you say me your rspec version?

Comment: The accepted answer here may provide some explanation: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10842448/do-routing-specs-support-redirect-routes-rspec?rq=1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot use `route_to` matcher with a redirect route, because Rails handle redirect routes differently. A redirect route has no controller, where `route_to` test to/from a controller.

In your case you need to use a **request** spec:

```
describe "activation Urls" do
  before { get '/a/12341234' } 
  it { response.should redirect_to(Rails.application.config.url_homepage) }
end
```